# Solving $(4y+2x-5)dx+(6y+4x-1)dy=0$ using 2 methods produced 2 different answers!

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$(4y+2x-5)dx+(6y+4x-1)dy=0,y(-1)=2$$

First method:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{4y+2x-5}{6y+4x-1}$$

let $Y=y-\frac{9}{2}$, $dY=dy$  and $X=x+\frac{13}{2}$, $dX=dx$;
$$\frac{dY}{dX}=-\frac{4Y+2X}{6Y+4X}$$
let $u=\frac{Y}{X}$ , $Y'=u'X+u$;
$$u'X+u=-\frac{4u+2}{6u+4}$$
$$u'X=\frac{-6u^2-8u-2}{6u+4}$$
$$\int\frac{(6u+4)du}{6u^2+8u+2}=\int-\frac{dX}{X}$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\ln|3u^2+4u+1|=-\ln|X|+Constant$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\ln|3(\frac{y-\frac{9}{2}}{x+\frac{13}{2}})^2+4(\frac{y-\frac{9}{2}}{x+\frac{13}{2}})+1|=-\ln|x+\frac{13}{2}|+Constant$$

Solving for $y(-1)=2$, $Constant=0.89587977346$;
$$\frac{1}{2}\ln|3(\frac{y-\frac{9}{2}}{x+\frac{13}{2}})^2+4(\frac{y-\frac{9}{2}}{x+\frac{13}{2}})+1|=-\ln|x+\frac{13}{2}|+0.89587977346$$

Second method:

let $M=4y+2x-5$ , $N=6y+4x-1$
$$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}=4\rightarrow Exact$$
$$\varnothing=4xy+x^2-5x+3y^2-y=Constant$$

Solving for $y(-1)=2$, $Constant=8$;
$$\varnothing=4xy+x^2-5x+3y^2-y=8$$

I plotted those two answers on MATHEMATICA and found that result:

[image]

How could the results be different?

Answer (score 1):

The indefinite integration formula
$$
\int \frac{dU}{U} = \ln |U| + c
\tag{1}
$$
(correctly) summarizes *two* formulas that hold in disjoint intervals,
$$
\left.
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{dU}{U} &= \ln U + c    &&(U > 0), \\
\int \frac{dU}{U} &= \ln (-U) + c && (U < 0).
\end{aligned}\right\}
\tag{2}
$$
(I'm deliberately using $U$ as a variable since it does not appear in your situation.)

In any particular *definite* integral (such as in your case, solving an ODE with an initial condition), only one choice of sign in (2) is correct.

As a result, your first method (using (1)) led to an equation of the form $|U| = C$, i.e., $U = \pm C$,  when it should have led (using *one* equation from (2)) to $U = C$.

As visual confirmation, the dashed curve you expected comprises two branches of the hyperbola $4xy + x^{2} - 5x + 3y^{2} - y = C$; the "extra" portion comprises the two branches of the hyperbola $4xy + x^{2} - 5x + 3y^{2} - y = -C$.

Comment: hmmm, Ok. If I used the first method only, then how to extract the right formula, I have initial value and got the constant which produced a formula describing two hyperbolas. How to extract the right curve ?

Comment: After integrating (and algebraic rearrangement) you have an equation of the form $\ln|U| = C$, which can be written $|U| = e^{C}$, and then $U = \pm e^{C}$, with $A = \pm e^{C}$ representing an "arbitrary constant". Substituting the initial condition at this stage gives the "correct" value of $A$, i.e., the desired solution. (By contrast, substituting the initial condition before removing the absolute value sign gives |U| = e^{C}$, namely, _both_ signs $U = \pm e^{C}$, i.e., "extra" solutions.)